# String not recognized as DateTime using ParseExact in a C# Script inside a biztalk map

Tags: c#, biztalk

Previous working version of the map:

[image: Previous working version]

In this version the input Data is of the type xs:date

The Target version of the map:

[image: Target version]

In this version I changed the Data type to xs:string in the flatfile. I also added the following C# script that's highlighted in the new map:

```
public static System.DateTime MyConcat(string param1)
{   
    string[] formats = { "yyyy\\/MM\\/dd", "dd-MM-yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd", "dd\\/MM\\/yyyy" };
    return System.DateTime.ParseExact(param1, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None); 
}
```

[image: Script Functoid]

I'm passing to the Data input the string '2018-03-15'.

The error I get:

> ABC.MW.BackEnds.CENTRAL.DocsInformacaoFinanceira.Balancete.Mappers.MapBalancete. Error:Transformation failed.. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: An error occurred during a call to extension function 'DateFormat'. See InnerException for a complete description of the error. ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)

From the error I deduct the problem is an implicit cast from string to datetime. But I don't see where it might be happening.

I found the origin of the error. It's the method call by the scriptoids that were in the previous working function.

I assume the xs:date and what my scriptoid returns are not the same thing.

The code of the function that was giving the error:

```
 public string DateFormat(string value, string FormatoOrigem, string FormatoDestino)
        {
            DateTime myDate;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                return ""; //myDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            else
                myDate = System.DateTime.ParseExact(value,
                                                FormatoOrigem,
                                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return myDate.ToString(FormatoDestino, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
```

The script that called the function inputs:

[image: Inputs of the script]

Comment: [ParseExact has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an array of string formats. You don't need that ugly series of ifs.

Comment: You haven't shown what the value is, which makes it hard to help. Why not add some logging for the value you're trying to convert first? (Having said that, there's nothing in the stack trace showing your method, so it's not clear whether it's being called at all...)

Comment: @Steve Thanks. I changed and updated the answer

Comment: @DaisyShipton I added it now. That error was with '2018-03-15'. But I also tried with 15-03-2018 and got the same error.

Comment: So how are you expecting your method to be called? I don't see any evidence that it *is* being called at the moment.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I don't understand your question. The method is the inline script of the script functoid I made. I added another screenshot to make it clearer.

Comment: Is that method *definitely* being called though? There's no sign of it in the stack trace. If you change it to just throw an exception of "My functoid was called" unconditionally, does that error message get shown?

Comment: @DaisyShipton the error is at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact, only my script uses that method

Comment: Don't you think it's at least worth checking that? It's talking about an extension method called `DateFormat`, but we've no idea what that is at the moment. Why don't you add `if (param1 == "2018-03-15") throw new Exception("Yes, it got to the method");` to your functoid? Surely it's at least worth taking the small amount of time to do that. Fundamentally, we don't know why the error is occurring. This test will add diagnostic information to help you track the problem down.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I did the test and it does reach the function.  System.Exception: Yes, it got to the method at System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.Script8.MyConcat(String param1)

The only place I can think DateFormat comes from is the ParseExact method. Maybe the parameter System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: Okay, it's good to rule that problem out. `DateFormat` isn't being called by `ParseExact` - it's the other way round, I believe. I suspect the `DateFormat` extension method is calling your functoid. Did you happen to capture the stack trace when you ran your test? I suspect that still have `DateFormat` in it.

Comment: @DaisyShipton There's no mention of DateFormat in the stack. 
I'll share the full stack trace but I don't think there's anything else relevant. http://txt.do/duz98

Comment: Okay, that's *very* important. That stack trace is completely different to the one in the question *and* it shows `MyConcat`. That strongly suggests that it's *not* this method that's throwing the exception, so you should look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateFormat function parameters are the date value, and 2 date formats. 
The call by the script functoid is passing the formats first and the value last.
This will cause the error in the function DateFormat when a call to the method ParseExact is using a format instead of a value.

Thanks to @Daisy Shipton for helping me see the error was outside the script I developed.
Thanks to @Johns-305 for helping me go after the real cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

We have to address this specifically for the BizTalk runtime.  So `DateFormat()` is the source of this error so you'll need to start there.

Also, keep in mind, there are time when DateTime is correct and times when returning a String is correct.  So, you many need to change the return type somewhere.

Comment: I found the DateFormat and it's in the next scriptoid. I was passing it xs:date in the working version which I believe is an xml element. Should I return a string and not a date in my function then?

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro Can <Data> really appear on all four formats?  That's quite unusual.

Comment: It's a project requirement. I wouldn't mind if it didn't either :D.

Comment: @AntonioCraveiro And what exactly does DateFormat do?  What input type does it take?  Do data and anoMes take the same format?

Comment: @john-305 I found the error. Earlier trying another solution I must have changed the order of the inputs in the script functoid. Which caused an incorrect call to the DateFormat function. I added some details in the question and in the answer I posted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19428203)

Comment: @YohDeadfall Yes, I know that.  The comments were overloaded with irrelevant cross talk.  This was to help OP, which it did so, no apologies.